# Can't install AMD Catalyst drivers on 13.04

Tags: unity, 13.04, catalyst

I recently installed Ubuntu 13.04 on a system with an AMD APU (A6-5400k). The unity sidebar was flickering and I had had this problem before, and installing the AMD Catalyst drivers fixed it (under 12.04.2). Under 13.04, when I try installing Catalyst 13.4 (what a coincidence) it says it is not an executable when I run the .run file using `sudo sh` or by making it executable under Properties. It is to the point of unusable as I am planning to play a few games on it. Can anyone point me in the direction of good open source drivers or how I can install the proprietary drivers? I am relatively new to Linux.

Comment: Apparently it won't work under the new version of the Linux kernel; anyone know how to make it compatible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to install Catalyst 13.4 please refer to those instructions:
http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Raring_Installation_Guide#Installing_Proprietary_Drivers_a.k.a._Catalyst.2Ffglrx